# Ordinal classes in a fast.ai ImageDataBunch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-recognition, fast-ai

I have ordinal categorical labels I want to use in an [ImageDataBunch](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.data.html#ImageDataBunch).

In my DataFrame I specify this as such:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=['L', 'M', 'H'], ordered=True)
label_df["adj_gr"] = label_df["adj_gr"].astype(cat_type)


#Series shows as: Categories (3, object): [L < M < H]
```

However when I made an `ImageDataBunch` from this column it reverts the categories to alphabetical order:

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_df("", df=label_df, fn_col="path", label_col="adj_gr", valid_pct=0.2,
        ds_tfms=tfms, size=224, num_workers=4, padding_mode='border').normalize(imagenet_stats)
data.classes
OUT: [H, L, M]
```

Does the order not matter for neural net like it does for ML models?

Its frustrating as when I have several categories and I `plot_confusion_matrix()` the labels are out of order and its hard to get a visualization of how good the model is at this.

Setup: `python==3.7, pytorch==1.4, fastai==1.0.60`

Comment: It's possible that `data.classes` just returns an unordered list of the classes, but that the data itself still remains ordered. Have you tried looking at `data` to see if it still makes sense?

Comment: I haven't, do you know how? dtype of `data` is an ImageDataBunch

Comment: It's been a little while since I've worked with Fastai, but try `data[0]` and `data[1]`. A databunch is really just a way of grouping training, validation, and test sets